# How do I create my own database instead of "Northwind sample database" MSDN mentions?

Tags: sql-server, database, northwind

[Every other SQL Server walkthrough](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171884%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) says I have to install "the Northwind sample database" and then connect to it. I find it ridiculous - I'd rather create a new empty database and then populate it.

What's so magic in that database? Why can't I create my own database? How do I create my own database instead of using "the Northwind sample database"?

Comment: I dont want to seem rude, but this is a silly question.

Comment: @astander: This is a *newbie question* and they are often *silly*.

Comment: Say what? you are a newbie? How you figure that?

Comment: @astander: I'm creating an SQL Server database for the first time in my career - do I qualify as an SQL Server newbie?

Comment: Yes, that will surely be newbie then. But even so, it is purely for demonstrational purposes then. This should be very clear. To explain certain details, it is better to use examples, and to standardize example to something that is available to everybody...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course you can use your own database if you want.  You'll just need to adapt the walkthrough to use your schema rather than the Northwind one.

There's nothing magic about Northwind, it's just a common and readily available database so that the focus of whatever is referencing it doesn't get tied up in designing a database to use and populating it with data.

You can find a walkthrough for creating your own database [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms233763%28v=VS.80%29.aspx).

Comment: The irony - it again mentions creating a connection to Northwind database.

Answer (score 1):

> What's so magic in that database?

There is no magic. It just a sample database with table definitions and some data.

> Why can't I create my own database?

You can.

> How do I create my own database instead of using "the Northwind sample database"?

You can use SQL Server Management Studio.

Connect to a server. Right-click on the `Databases` node and select `New Database...`.

Or you can write a [create database](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176061.aspx) command that you can run in SQL Server Management Studio query window.

This will create a database called TestDB

```
create database TestDB
```